# Deriving distribution over one partition from distribution over another

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two finite partitions of the outcome space, both with the same cardinality

$H_{1}, H_{2}, ...., H_{n}$ and $E_{1}, E_{2}, ..., E_{n}$

Since these form a partition, we know that $P(E_{1}) + P(E_{2}) + .... + P(E_{n}) = 1$ and $P(E_{i}|E_{j}) = 0$ for $i \neq j$, and similarly for the $H_{i}$'s.

Suppose further that we know the probability of all the $E_{i}$'s and the conditional probabilities $P(E_{i}|H_{j})$ for all $i, j \leq n$. Is it then possible to derive the probability of the $H_{j}$'s? If so, how?

Comment: By law of total probabilities, $\displaystyle P(E_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n P(E_i|H_j)P(H_j), i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ and you have $\sum_{i=1}^n P(E_i) = 1$, therefore you have a linear system to solve the unknowns $P(H_j)$

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But why are we guaranteed that the system of linear equations will have unique solutions?

Comment: There is no guarantee? You may need to have more assumption on the dependency. Say if $E_i$ and $H_j$ are mutually independent, for $n = 2$, then you have a system with infinitely many solutions. Not sure if linear independence of the system will imply some sort of independence between the partitions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So in the end there generally isn't any way to derive the distribution over the second partition from the first in this kind of case.